# Issues installing Ubuntu 14.04.1 on Windows 8 PC but works on other Windows 8 laptop

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-8

I downloaded the iso and created a liveUSB with Universal USB Installer. When I boot to the device, I have a choice to boot from USB: Sandisk 2GB or UEFI: Sandisk 2GB. I have the same result with both. It comes up to the menu to "Try Ubuntu", "Install Ubuntu", etc. When I click Install, it goes to the screen with the Ubuntu logo and the dots underneath, then after a minute or so my screens just go a faded purple and nothing happens (I left it there fore 15 minutes before restarting).

I then tried the same USB on the laptop, I only got the option to boot from USB: Sandisk 2 GB and everything worked fine.

Both latpop and desktop are running Windows 8 (not sure if one or the other is on 8.1, can check later)

I tried following this guide, [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported), but when I run the Confirm-SecureBootUEFI, I get that the cmdlet not supported so I figured I should just be able to install normally.

Comment: try to disable secure boot in bios config

Comment: Sounds like Laptop is BIOS only. What video card/chip do you have on Desktop? http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it Also if Windows is UEFI, then you really want to boot installer in UEFI mode, so it installs in UEFI mode. Otherwise dual booting is only possible from UEFI menu or perhaps one time boot key like f12.

Comment: @oldfred i5-3570k, AMD Radeon HD 7800, two monitors plugged into that card.

Comment: Almost all Intel i-series chips are UEFI based motherboards. but windows may be UEFI or BIOS boot. Do not know about AMD, but probably need nomodeset until you install proprietary drivers. http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it This shows nVidia, but I would expect you to see AMD? http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers

Answer (score 0):

try to use rufus https://rufus.akeo.ie/ will make   usb with uefi mode ( GPT Partition )